# Losing data while writing them in Cassandra due to timestamp (Timestamp precision)

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to write some numeric data in cassandra by using LabView. My code is the following.

[image: IMG. LabView code for writing data]

[image: Data in the table]

For example, i'm waiting for while loop to execute 100.000 iterations. I expected in data table in Cassandra there would be 100.000 rows with the timestamp according to them. But in my case there are only about 5500 rows, i.e. i'm losing my data during writing. I guess the reason is the timestamp. What is the precision of the Cassandra timestamp? (I mean when one is using toTimestamp(now()) function). Thank you.

Comment: Give us the Cassandra table definition and the insert statement being used?

Comment: Why don't you use timeuuid ? with only now() function ?

Comment: Still you are missing the C* table definition where you define what are the primary keys are and what columns belong in the table?

Comment: Thank you for comments.

I used the following command

[ CREATE TABLE test_table (name_id int, timestamp timestamp, value double, PRIMARY KEY (name_id, timestamp)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp asc) ]

Comment: Dear @dilsingi, there are some cases when I need to write not the time of now, but also the timestamp in past

Comment: I inserted data by the next way

insert into test_table (name_id, timestamp, value) values (1, toTimestamp(now()), an_bigint_number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a case like this, where you write very fast, you should use timeuuid to avoid collisions. See https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/uuid_type_r.html

Comment: Thank you for answer :) I have another question: is there any way to convert timestamp to timeuuid? I know there is the function, which converts timeuuid to timestamp, it is toTimestamp(timeuuid) fuction.

Comment: There is no such function in CQL, this has to be done in the client code.